# How can I replace this SMD diode?

Tags: diodes, integrated-circuit, surface-mount, replacement

[image]This "742 PG" seems found to be nowhere in any place.  What is the best SMD diode that can replace it?
It is from Lenze PCB for the 8211E variable frequency drive.

Please show me the way to replace it with an equivalent one.

[image]

Comment: Search for pwr diode maybe BVxxx in same package or search SMD codes here looks like >1A is best way to read specs

Comment: If you have space, you don't need to replace with a SMD equivalent. You can just extract two wires out to solder an ordinary through hole diode. You might like to see an example of extracting two wires to solder a replacement of SMD polyfuse with a through hole polyfuse: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/104596/rpi3b-micro-usb-connector-got-15v-power-is-it-dead-can-i-save-it.

Comment: So you can replace the SMD 742 with 1N742 or a similar but higher rating 1N742xx. Good luck and cheer.

Comment: Without knowledge of the circuit in which it comes from, it's unlikely you'll be able to match all the data sheet parameters for the diode. If you compromise and match or exceed some parameters you might risk further damage. So what do you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

The chances are good that this is a [1SMA4742](https://img.ozdisan.com/ETicaret_Dosya/472270_4941496.pdf) 12 volt Zener diode.

The datasheet is from a different manufacturer, but I'm pretty sure it is the part you need.  Other companies that make the 1SMA4742 also mark them "472."

The "PG" is probably a date code.  The comment from tlfong01 suggests it might be code indication packaging material.  That may well be true.

---

From looking around, it seems the 1SMA4742 is a surface mount version of the [1N4742](https://www.vishay.com/docs/85816/1n4728a.pdf) 12V Zener diode.  The 1N4742 comes in a conventional through hole housing, and may be more commonly available.

Comment: Ah, PG usually denotes package material, P means plastic, I don't know what is G.